# How can I call console controllers

Tags: plugin-development, ajax, controller, console

I have a controller in the console folder. How can I call this controller via ajax please?

I tried to config a route in `Routes.php`, and then call this route by jquery `Get()` function. But none of these below work...

```
'api/v0/hub-loader/<sheet_id:\d+>' => 'craftplugin/import-hubs/test',
'api/v0/hub-loader/<sheet_id:\d+>' => 'craftplugin/console/controllers/import-hubs/test',
'api/v0/hub-loader/<sheet_id:\d+>' => 'craftplugin/console/import-hubs/test',
```

All these routes return `404 page not found error`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to get around this problem by creating a controller which extends the console controller. 
Then I can call the functions in this child controller.

But if anyone knows how to call console controllers directly, please tell me.Thx