# How to run custom module controller actions from console?

Tags: modules, custom, cli, console

I have built a custom module with some custom controller actions - some of which I would like to run via console, but I am not sure what the path/command should be for running these actions?

In my `routes.php` I have:
`'action/my-action' => 'custom-module/custom-controller/custom-action'`

Is it based on the URL route, or the module command, or something else?

Things like `./craft action/my-action` or `./craft custom-module/custom-controller/custom-action` do not work and return:

```
Unknown command: custom-module/custom-controller/custom-action
Caused by: Exception 'yii\base\InvalidRouteException' with message 'Unable to resolve the request "custom-module/custom-controller/custom-action".'
```

We have got the following in our module which I thought would make web controllers "just work" but it does not:

```
if (Craft::$app->getRequest()->getIsConsoleRequest()) {
  $this->controllerNamespace = 'custom-module\\console\\controllers';
}
```

And an example controller/action: https://gist.github.com/iamkeir/5929a7da368e9b74e93c330f504d0bd1

Thanks!

Comment: Related: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/27321/how-can-i-call-console-controllers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed this - was due to a couple of issues with this line:

```
if (Craft::$app->getRequest()->getIsConsoleRequest()) {
  $this->controllerNamespace = 'custom-module\\console\\controllers';
}
```

1. My controller was in `custom-module/controllers`, not `custom-module/console/controllers` so it was not finding the controller.
2. My module is namespaced as `namespace modules\custom-module` so I needed to add `modules\\` to my controller namespace override: `$this->controllerNamespace = 'modules\\custom-module\\console\\controllers'`

Now `./craft custom-module/custom-controller/custom-action` works!